# JPA and Play Framework: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named update

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using Play! Framework 2.0.2, when I add several items from my java project to my H2 test database I only see one single item in the ITEM table. The single item being the last entry that i've persisted. I thought that this my be due the db being recreated at every commit. I therefor thought of adding the JPA.ddl=update property in my application.conf file. But this simply breaks with the following error. What

Here is my code (in the Item.save() method):

```
package models;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String dev;
    public String type;
    public int quantity;
    public BigDecimal unitPrice;

    public Item() {}

    public Item(String name, String dev, String type, int quantity,
            BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.dev = dev;
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Insert this new computer.
     */
    public void save() {
        //this.id = id;
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(this);        
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named update
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.
Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.
Final]
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
```

Comment: Just curious, if you're testing P2 why don't you go with Ebean ?

Comment: I have not delved too deep into Ebean since I think I read somewhere that it was still experimental. Are you saying that it is more advantageous to work with Ebean rather then this method?

Comment: I can not imagine working with JPA if I don't need to and if I can work with Ebean in P2, it's just definitely more comfortable. No, it's not experimental, it's fully implemented and P2 is working with stable version of Ebean. I'd suggest to watch the sample apps (ie. computer-database for java) and at least take the Ebean to the test-drive

Comment: I cannot agree here - Ebean is outdated (does not support JPA 2, only 1, and only parts), bad documented and development seems to have stalled. It's often a pain because of small issues stealing time here and there. Check with the Play mailinglist: Ebean will be replaced with JPA as default ORM in Play 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're going to need a persistence.xml file to be contained within your /conf/META-INF/ directory, and from there need to define a persistence unit. I believe this is because you're using Hibernate correct?

An example of what yours can look like

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="update">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:events"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

In your  tag you'll also need to include any `<jar-file>` or `<class>` you are to be using as well.

Comment: Yes, Jeff. I am using hibernate. I found out that my problem was in my persistence.xml file. where I wrongfully set the value of hibernate.hbm2ddl to"create-drop". It all works fine when I change this to "update", like in your example. Also, i had to remove the entry in my configuration file, /META-INF/application.conf, where i stated jpa.ddl=update. Thanks